# can't drop db posgres using dropdb command in terminal?

Tags: postgresql

When I do `\l` I see `myexampledb`, then I do dropdb 'myexampledb' in the terminal, I got no error, I do `\l` again, the db isn't deleted, what's wrong?

I did this exactly:

1. I do `psql`
2. I got error of `psql: FATAL:  database "steven" does not exist`
3. I do `psql -d postgres`
4. I do `dropdb 'postgres'`
5. I do `\ls`
6. the postgres db isn't removed

Comment: Please show us **exactly** where and how you ran those query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated my question, I'm curious why do I have error in step 2

Comment: you need to `createdb steven` first.

Comment: @a_horse_withi_no_name which command I need `;`? I can't do dropdb 'postgres';`, I got syntax error.

Comment: any clue why I got `postgres=# dropdb 'postgres';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "dropdb"
LINE 1: dropdb 'postgres';
        ^
postgres=#` ??